# Simple "Hello World" program giving segmentation fault in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, segmentation-fault, msys2

I recently installed *MinGW* from *MSYS2*, and tested the program below:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World";
  return 0 ;
}
```

But I get a segmentation fault in *VS Code*.
The same code runs fine in *CodeBlocks* and in the *MSYS2* terminal.

Seems like I get the error, whenever there are `cout` or `cin` statements.
I did do `pacman -Syuu` to update the msys2 packages, but to no use.

**launch.json**:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": " ${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            // "sourceFileMap": {
            //     "/mnt/c": "C:/msys64/mingw64"
            // },

            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe ",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

[image: callstack]

Comment: Did everything build as it should? (no warnings etc..?). Offtopic : stop using `using namespace std;`

Comment: Fwiw: Your program is perfectly fine and compiling it and running it should not present any problems. I'd blame something in the environment.

Comment: @PepijnKramer No warnings .

Comment: Either VSCode incorrectly configured (where have we heard that one before) or g++ incorrectly configured. To find out which take VSCode out of the equation, try building your program and running it from the command line, do you get the same problem?

Comment: Since the problems involve iostream my guess is that the fundamental reason is that you have a version conflict in the standard library. For example you include headers for one version of the standard library but link a different version of the standard library.

Comment: ¿Which line is causing  segmentation fault? You should post a call stack.

Comment: @user7860670 , the  hello world line gives the error .

Comment: First test if you can build and run a hello world program inside the mingw64 terminal. That should be an easy test. My guess is you have more than 1 version of MinGW installed and your `PATH` environment variable contains the `old`  version first causing a dll conflict.

Comment: Sounds like a DLL conflict to me. Build **and run** from MSYS2 MINGW64 shell for a test.

Comment: @drescherjm I cant build and run in the mingw4 terminal either, get  a long list of errors , cant make sense of it , I had a different mingw before, but I deleted it , and removed it from the system environment variables too

Comment: ***get a long list of errors*** What did you type? `g++ main.cpp` or something similar?

Comment: @ `g++ main.cpp -o main` and then `g++ main.exe`

Comment: If that failed my advice is to uninstall msys2 and reinstall. Then test again.  You may also want to remove the other MinGW you have installed.

Comment: `g++ main.exe` makes no sense. You want `./main.exe`.

Comment: If you're on Windows why are you using VSCode and msys32? Use Visual Studio with Microsoft's C and C++ compiler. There's no need to use mingw on Windows when better compilers and development environments than VSCode and CodeBlocks exist.

Comment: @Irelia Arguably GCC/Clang *are* better compilers.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what you do in the MINGW64 terminal and how the program doesn't run in there.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat MinGW better than Microsoft's own compiler optimized for their own operating system perfect synergy with their own IDE? I find that incredibly hard to believe.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , I managed to run in mingw terminal ,(prefixed the './') it works fine ,but problem persists in vs code

Comment: @Irelia Yes. From my experience, it's the least conforming to the standard out of the big tree (not in now fast it implements the features, but in quality of implementation), has the worst diagnostics out of the three (for me, neither GCC nor Clang never failed to print a complete instantiation stack when encountering an error in templates, while MSVC sometimes either doesn't print the stack or doesn't print the template arguments in it). When writing complex templates at work, it's only only compiler that I've had frequent internal compiler errors in. And so on...

Comment: As for performance, I didn't measure, but google doesn't reveal any drastic differences.

Comment: @akashKP Then the problem is that you have weird DLLs in PATH. Make sure `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` is the first entry both in system-wide PATH and in user PATH. If that doesn't help, check which dirs in PATH contain `libstdc++-6.dll` and remove them from PATH.

Answer (score 3):

After lots of futile attempts to fix the error, I managed to fix the problem th e problem by moving  the path to `mingw\bin` to the top in the environment variables both in user and System variables paths list .

The source of the problem was that I had multiple `libstdc++-6.dll` files of different applications whose path was above the paths of msys2  `libstdc++-6.dll` , which resulted in the wrong version of the library being called .(thanks to @HolyBlackCat for pointing this out) .

Answer (score 3):

I had the same situation as well. I got mad with this problem for few days.

The problem is in `tasks.command` in `tasks.json` file. The default path is `"C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"`, if you follow the steps from [vscode website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_prerequisites). I rewrote the double backslash into slash, i.e. `"C:/msys64/mingw64/in/g++.exe"`. This works for me!

You can set the compiler path in settings to `"C:/msys64/mingw64/in/g++"` so that you don't have to rewrite path in `tasks.json` file every time you build a new project.

Answer (score 2):

I just compile with -static

```
/c/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -static -g -o tmp.exe tmp.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I attempted to execute the exe program in Git Bash, but it produced the same error. However, when I ran it in Powershell, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the executable file in powershall, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick note** : the issue, as mentionned earlier in the comments, might be because your `default terminal in Vscode` is set to `git bash` (created while installing git for windows) and not to `windows powershell`. Seems that there are some DLLs incompatible between the last `C++ mingw64` and the one installed with git.

The "best" solution to me was to uninstall git for windows and re-install it,  but not in the default folder showed during the installation process. The prevent me from playing with the PATH system environment variable in both linux subsystem and wnidows.

Then, C++ could be executed in both terminals (`git bash` or `powershell`) without any issue.

Hope this helps, I spent a whole morning to find and fix this issue.