# Segmentation fault in c++ in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, segmentation-fault, mingw, iostream

While trying to run this simple hello world program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

I get segmentation fault error:

```
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\libstdc++-6.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\libwinpthread-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000006fcbacf6 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry (this=this@entry=0x5ffde0, __os=...) at ./build/x86_64-w64-mingw32-posix/x86_64-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc:51
```

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Almost always it is an installation/configuration issue. Leading to incorrect linking.

Comment: Why is it grabbing some of the libraries from `Tesseract-OCR`? So yeah, those are probably a different version than your program needs and hence the crash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495365/simple-hello-world-program-giving-segmentation-fault-in-vs-code

Comment: Welcome to the DLL hell.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI That too could be a very real possibility. Though it is strange those dll's get pulled in for an hello world program

Comment: The bug is here: `Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.` You have an incompatible version of MinGW runtime in your `PATH`. This is definitely [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell)

Comment: Also did you follow the official VSCode MinGW instructions: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) I ask this because many new users don't follow the instructions and instead install MinGW in some other method which is more difficult, more error prone and less useful than the official instructions.

Comment: @drescherjm I did follow the official guide

Comment: That's good.  If you don't know the solution yet, you need to get the folder of `Tesseract-OCR` out of your OS `PATH` environment variable to fix your MinGW in VSCode however that will likely break `Tesseract-OCR` so if you need to use that you may have to put the `PATH` back when you want to use that.

Comment: If you don't want to modify your OS PATH environment variable you can modify your terminal settings in VSCode to set the PATH environment variable in the terminal: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/how-can-i-globally-set-the-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/how-can-i-globally-set-the-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code)