# Clion Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) problem

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mingw, clion, exit-code

I reinstalled JetBrains Clion and an error started appearing
`Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` when running this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::cout << "ASD";
}
```

When debugging, a segfault appears on the line `std::cout << "ASD";`
The code works correctly when `printf` is used instead of `std::cout`. :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    printf("ASD");
}
```

I'm using bundled MinGW

What could be the problem and how it can be solved?

I tried installing MinGW and using not bundled version, but that didn't work

Comment: ***What could be the problem and how it can be solved?*** Most likely [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) caused by you having more than 1 version of the MinGW runtime dlls in your OS PATH environment variable and your OS finding the incompatible version first.

Comment: Its solved by inspecting your OS `PATH` environment variable to check if MinGW dlls appear in any folder listed in the PATH. And I am not necessarily talking about MinGW itself here. Yesterday this same problem was caused by `Tesseract-OCR` being in the path in VSCode causing the a crash in MinGW. In that case the IDE showed the problem in the log by showing that the runtime dlls were loaded from the `Tesseract-OCR` folder.

Comment: Here is that question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78022547/segmentation-fault-in-c-in-visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78022547/segmentation-fault-in-c-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: The most important dlls to look for are likely: `libstdc++-6.dll`, `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` and `libwinpthread-1.dll` these should be loaded from your MinGW bin folder and not some other program's folder because the other folder could have a different incompatible version that could cause a crash like you see.

Comment: @drescherjm. I had this dlls: `libstdc++-6.dll`, `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` and `libwinpthread-1.dll` in folder C:\Windows\System32. 
Found the same problem as mine: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495365/simple-hello-world-program-giving-segmentation-fault-in-vs-code)
There in the comments: "Then the problem is that you have weird DLLs in PATH. Make sure C:\msys64\mingw64\bin is the first entry both in system-wide PATH and in user PATH. If that doesn't help, check which dirs in PATH contain libstdc++-6.dll and remove them from PATH."

Comment: But in my case I dont think its fine to remove system32 folder
Can I delete these 3 dlls from system32?

Comment: Yes those dlls should have never been put in system32 in the first place. You may want to  make a copy of them then delete them. For the system32 you will get a UAC prompt.