# cin is not working in a Do..While loop, program is crashing directly after start

Tags: c++, loops, iostream, cin

I'm a C++ beginner, and I got stuck at a self training.

I want to do a number guessing game - pretty easy task, basically.

The issue appears in the `do..while` loop. I want to read in a number from the user until the right one is guessed. When I start the program, it crashes because it's always looping the `cout` and `cin` but it should wait at `cin` until there is an input. Why does this happen? If I would do a program just with one try, the program is waiting, until there is an input.

So, my thought was to do a `do..while` loop, because I want at least to go through one time.

I would appreciate some input so I can do more research about this issue.

In my training, I have done:

- Variables, Const, Datatypes & Operations
- Logical operators and comparison operators
- control structures & loops
- functions

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int eingabe = 0;
    int randomZahl = 8;
    bool checker = true;

    cout << "Number Guesser\n\n";

    do
    {
        if(eingabe != randomZahl)
        {
            cout << "Bitte gib eine Zahl ein: ";
            cin >> eingabe;
        }

        if(eingabe == randomZahl)
        {
        checker = false;
        }


    }while(checker);

    return 0;

}
```

This is how the crash looks:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I think [your program should work](https://ideone.com/v3KjoR).

Comment: Is it crashing with a message?

Comment: Does a "Hello World" program crash? If so its likely [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) and it seems like we get one question every day that is about that for VSCode or MinGW. Here is the question from yesterday: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031307/clion-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005-problem#comment137570330_78031307](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031307/clion-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005-problem#comment137570330_78031307)

Comment: Do you really mean crash or is it looping forever because of instead of typing a number you typed "frog"?

Comment: How are you running the program? Is it from the command line or from a specific IDE? Also, is it running locally or remote (or in a VM/Container)?

Comment: Your picture does not look like a crash. It looks like an infinite loop because of bad data and not resetting the error state.

Comment: I've added a picture of the crash. Qt is not useable anymore and after some seconds its away. And I test it in the terminal of Qt and Hello World or if I use cin outside of a loop it also works properly. Its just in the while. Like the text befor the loop also appers one time and as it should.

Comment: Could maybe just the compiler be bad? Bc on a online compiler its working. The compilers name is CMake (i guess)

Comment: ***Could maybe just the compiler be bad?*** I don't think this is a compiler problem but it possibly could be related to my first comment if you are on the MS Windows OS. Having DLL Hell causes undefined behavior which could make your code misbehave.

Comment: ***The compilers name is CMake (i guess)*** No, CMake is not a compiler. It's a tool to generate project files / Make files for your actual compiler. [https://cmake.org/](https://cmake.org/)

Answer (score 2):

### You are not checking to make sure the user enters a valid integer.

If they do not enter a valid integer, `operator>>` will put `cin` into an error state that you are not clearing. That will then cause `operator>>` to stop waiting for subsequent input, causing your loop to run forever.

Try this instead (forgive me if the German is wrong, I used Google Translate):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int eingabe, randomZahl = 8;

    cout << "Number Guesser\n\n";

    do
    {
        cout << "Bitte gib eine Zahl ein: ";
        if (cin >> eingabe)
        {
            if (eingabe == randomZahl)
            {
                cout << "Du hast richtig geraten!\n";
                break;
            }

            cout << "Du hast falsch geraten! Versuchen Sie es erneut.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            cout << "Sie haben falsche Daten eingegeben! Versuchen Sie es erneut.\n";
        }
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't know yet that its even possible to get en cin input in a if statment, at least something new lerned ;) But about the issue, I loaded the code int Visual Studio 2022 and there it worked fine (your code) but in Qt same issue. In this case, idk whats the issue but its something on Qt side. Thanks anyway for your code!

Comment: @LostSicilian "*Didn't know yet that its even possible to get en cin input in a if statment*" - `operator>>` return a reference to the input stream, and `std::istream` has a [boolean conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). As such, `if (cin >> eingabe)` is functionally identical to doing `cin >> eingabe; if (!cin.fail())` "*idk whats the issue but its something on Qt side*" - then you need to update your question (or post a new one) to show the actual Qt code you are having trouble with. Because the code you did show here has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: I think they are using Qt-Creator as the IDE and don't understand what compiler its using.